# Maximal Clique partition of vertices with smallest number of cut edges

Tags: clique, partition-problem

I am given a simple undirected graph $G(V, E)$. I want to partition $V$ into $b$ Maximal cliques: $\{C_1, C_2, ..., C_b\}$ such that the number of edges that cut across two cliques is the minimum. $b$ is arbitrary i.e. there is no restriction on $b$.

I think the decision version of this problem is NP-Complete. It may be reduced to a weighted independent set problem. My question is:

Is there any known approximate algorithm for this problem?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: What is the parameter that you are optimizing? Is it the total number of edges outside the cliques?

Comment: Also, is it mandatory that the cliques are maximal? (i.e, are not contained in larger cliques)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover_problem is already NP-complete.

Comment: It could fall into the big family of **clustering** problems (splitting a graph into dense subgraphs with few edges in between)... you can always try to look for papers with this keyword.

Comment: Hi Igor, Yes, I am optimizing the total number of edges that are outside the cliques. And, yes it is required that that the cliques are maximal, otherwise one can simply consider 2-sized cliques and find a maximum matching solution where the optimal solution is be number of unmatched edges.

Comment: Hi  András, Yes, it is has similarity to clique cover problem. But the objective is different. Here I want to minimize the number of edges that are outside the cliques, but traditional clique cover problem minimize the number of cliques.

Comment: Hi tarulen, Yes, it falls into some form of graph clustering where each partition is dense subgraph. However, I am explicitly looking for maximal clique as each partition, and want to optimize the number of cut edges. I am almost certain that it is NP-complete, so I am looking for a solution that can give some approximation guarantee. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to have happen when the graph has no such partition (as, for instance, the diamond graph formed by removing an edge from $K_4$ doesn't)?

Comment: Following up on David Eppstein's question, is it clear that the decision version of the problem is poly-time solvable? That is, can we decide whether G can be partitioned into p maximal cliques? It is probably hard by appropriate modification from the standard clique cover/coloring hardness reduction.

Comment: David, for a diamond graph we have two maximal cliques: one is a triangle (3 vertices) and the other is a single vertex (no edge). The optimal solution is 2 as there are two edges crossing these two partitions.

Comment: That is false. The single vertex is not a maximal clique.

Comment: Agree, the problem is ill-defined. Thanks David and chandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is the Cluster Edge Deletion problem.

> Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and an integer, can we delete at most $k$ edges $F \subseteq E$ such that $G-F$ is a *cluster graph*?

A cluster graph here is a graph whose connected components are cliques.

The approximability of Cluster (Edge) Deletion, was studied by Shamir, Sharan, and Tsur (*Cluster graph modification problems.* Discrete Applied Mathematics, 144(1):173–182, 2004).  They show that the problem is **NP-hard to approximate within a constant factor**:

> **Theorem 12.** There is some constant $\epsilon > 0$ such that it is NP-hard to approximate Cluster Deletion to within a factor of $1 + \epsilon$.

Comment: I like this formulation. This is possibly a proper formulation of the problem that I am trying to solve.